# How to use trycatch in a web crawler to continue a for-loop in R?

Tags: r, web-crawler, try-catch

I'm a new learner for R and I write the following codes to get information from lots of webs. I want to continue the loop when error occurs, and I don't need to know the specific error message. Although I know trycatch can solve this problem, I failed and failed again. The errors always are  `Error: unexpected ')' in "  )"` and `Error: unexpected '}' in "}"`. How can I modify my codes?

```
library(RCurl)
library(XML)
shehui = data.frame()
for (i in 16088:17000){
  url = paste("http://www.society.shu.edu.cn/CN/abstract/abstract", i,     ".shtml", sep = "")
  tryCatch({
    web = getURL(url, encoding = "utf-8")
    html = htmlParse(web, encoding = "utf-8")
    y = getNodeSet(html, path =     "//td[@align='center']//td[@align='left']//a[@class='txt_zhaiyao']")
    year = xmlValue(y[[2]]) 
    issue = xmlValue(y[[4]])
    shehui = rbind(shehui, data.frame(url, year, issue, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
  }
  error = function(e) NULL,
  finally = print(url)
  )
}
shehui
```

Thanks!

Comment: You need a comman after `}` and before `error`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I just add a comma after } the codes run successfully!